Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/template/fragment.html]
I have not created the fragment.html file but when I build and run it on the web, the error Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/template/fragment.html]
What should I do to solve this problem?

Instead of putting your static file in /WEB-INF put your static html in src/main/resources/static
I am assuming that there is nothing special set in your application.properties/yml for serving up static html.
